# How to use autocorrect and spell check in iOS custom keyboard?

Tags: ios, autocomplete, keyboard, custom-keyboard

I have developed a custom keyboard and I need to add auto-correct and spell-check functionality to it. 
Using UITextChecker for word completions and guesses does not give very good results and is quite different from the native keyboard. 
For e.g. typing "there" suggests

Word Completions : [Thereabout, Thereabouts, Thereafter, Thereat, Thereby, Therefor, Therefore, Therefrom, Therein, Thereof, Thereon, Thereto, Thereunder, Thereunto, Thereupon, Therewith, There].

Word guesses : ["Their", "Three", "Thera", "Therm", "Theme", "These", "Where", "Here", "Thee", "Theres"].

While the native keyboard suggests totally different results.

Is there a different way to add efficient auto-correct and spell-check functionality?

Comment: Can you use the UITextInputTraits protocol?

Comment: @squarehippo10 Since I am having a custom keyboard, I do not have a textfield of my own and have access to UITextDocumentProxy.

Comment: Yeah, UITextChecker is pretty useless with the ordering. The best way to get this done or at least they way i managed was to implement a custom spell checker. After some research this link should be helpful http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html they have a swift solution in there which should be helpful. Also explain how a spell checker will work.